# How do I use the glm() function?

Tags: r, linear-regression, glm, lm, p-value

I'm trying to fit a general linear model (GLM) on my data using R. I have a Y continuous variable and two categorical factors, A and B. Each factor is coded as 0 or 1, for presence or absence.

Even if just looking at the data I see a clear interaction between A and B, the GLM says that p-value>>>0.05. Am I doing something wrong?

First of all I create the data frame including my data for the GLM, which consists on a Y dependent variable and two factors, A and B. These are two level factors (0 and 1). There are 3 replicates per combination.

```
A<-c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1)
B<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
Y<-c(0.90,0.87,0.93,0.85,0.98,0.96,0.56,0.58,0.59,0.02,0.03,0.04)
my_data<-data.frame(A,B,Y)
```

Let’s see how it looks like:

```
my_data
##    A B    Y
## 1  0 0 0.90
## 2  0 0 0.87
## 3  0 0 0.93
## 4  1 0 0.85
## 5  1 0 0.98
## 6  1 0 0.96
## 7  0 1 0.56
## 8  0 1 0.58
## 9  0 1 0.59
## 10 1 1 0.02
## 11 1 1 0.03
## 12 1 1 0.04
```

As we can see just looking on the data, there is a clear interaction between factor A and factor B, as the value of Y dramatically decreases when A and B are present (that is A=1 and B=1). However, using the glm function I get no significant interaction between A and B, as p-value>>>0.05

```
attach(my_data)
## The following objects are masked _by_ .GlobalEnv:
## 
##     A, B, Y


my_glm<-glm(Y~A+B+A*B,data=my_data,family=binomial)
## Warning: non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
summary(my_glm)
## 
## Call:
## glm(formula = Y ~ A + B + A * B, family = binomial, data = my_data)
## 
## Deviance Residuals: 
##       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max  
## -0.275191  -0.040838   0.003374   0.068165   0.229196  
## 
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
## (Intercept)   2.1972     1.9245   1.142    0.254
## A             0.3895     2.9705   0.131    0.896
## B            -1.8881     2.2515  -0.839    0.402
## A:B          -4.1747     4.6523  -0.897    0.370
## 
## (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
## 
##     Null deviance: 7.86365  on 11  degrees of freedom
## Residual deviance: 0.17364  on  8  degrees of freedom
## AIC: 12.553
## 
## Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

Comment: `attach` here is unnecessary and not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Konrad, I have ran the script without attaching and I get the same result (that is no interaction between A and B) Why do you think I get this? The interaction is clear in other statistical softwares like SPSS or Minitab...

Comment: I honestly think that your `family` is simply not adequately modelling the data. If you omit it, you get a significant correlation.

Comment: You probably want a different model if y is continuous. Perhaps the gamma distribution if it is strictly positive with no upper boundary or maybe a beta distribution if it is between 0 and 1. If instead, each observation represents a proportion of individual units, you might try a logistic regression by adding weights and the proper family / link arguments.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I agree, I’m not saying that it’s the same, just that binomial isn’t a good fit to model your error distribution.

Comment: You have a continuous explained by factors. To me is better to do an analysis of variance `aov`

Comment: To me, the results of a regular old `lm` function look quite reasonable when comparing the raw data.  ` summary(lm(Y~factor(A)*factor(B),data=my_data))`.

Comment: You have very little data and so it isn't surprising you don't find statistical significance with a logistic regression model. As a very rough rule of thumb, for MLE models like logits, I don't trust the results until I have 100 observations plus 10 for every covariate. And that's with well-behaved data. In this case, you would be best sticking with a linear model, assuming you want to model it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The family=binomial implies Logit (Logistic) Regression, which is itself produces a binary result.

From [Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/glm.html)

> Logistic Regression
>
> Logistic regression is useful when you are predicting a binary outcome
>   from a set of continuous predictor variables. It is frequently
>   preferred over discriminant function analysis because of its less
>   restrictive assumptions.

Comment: This is actually not a very good answer at all. The reason the interaction is insignificant in the GLM model is that there are very few degrees of freedom (small sample size) and because what little variation there is over these few rows of data is being controlled for by the main effects. To pick up an interaction effect you'd want about 10x as many rows. You can see this with a Power Analysis. Moreover it is extremely commonplace in statistical, econometric and other quantitative research journals to have logit models with categorical independent variables.

Answer (score 1):

While you state `Y` is continuous, the data shows that `Y` is rather a fraction.  Hence, probably the reason you tried to apply `GLM` in the first place.

To model fractions (i.e. continuous values bounded by 0 and 1) can be done with logistic regression if certain assumptions are fullfilled. See the following cross-validated post for details: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26762/how-to-do-logistic-regression-in-r-when-outcome-is-fractional. However, from the data description it is not clear that those assumptions are fullfilled.

An alternative to model fractions are beta regression or fractional repsonse models.

See below how to apply those methods to your data. The results of both methods are consistent in terms of signs and significance.

```
# Beta regression
install.packages("betareg")
library("betareg")
result.betareg <-betareg(Y~A+B+A*B,data=my_data)
summary(result.betareg)

# Call:
#   betareg(formula = Y ~ A + B + A * B, data = my_data)
# 
# Standardized weighted residuals 2:
#   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -2.7073 -0.4227  0.0682  0.5574  2.1586 
# 
# Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
#   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)   2.1666     0.2192   9.885  < 2e-16 ***
#   A             0.6471     0.3541   1.828   0.0676 .  
#   B            -1.8617     0.2583  -7.206 5.76e-13 ***
#   A:B          -4.2632     0.5156  -8.268  < 2e-16 ***
#   
#   Phi coefficients (precision model with identity link):
#   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
# (phi)    71.57      29.50   2.426   0.0153 *
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 
# 
# Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
# Log-likelihood: 24.56 on 5 Df
# Pseudo R-squared: 0.9626
# Number of iterations: 62 (BFGS) + 2 (Fisher scoring) 


# ----------------------------------------------------------


# Fractional response model
install.packages("frm")
library("frm")
frm(Y,cbind(A, B, AB=A*B),linkfrac="logit")


*** Fractional logit regression model ***

#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# INTERCEPT  2.197225   0.157135  13.983    0.000 ***
#   A          0.389465   0.530684   0.734    0.463    
#   B         -1.888120   0.159879 -11.810    0.000 ***
#   AB        -4.174668   0.555642  -7.513    0.000 ***
#   
#   Note: robust standard errors
# 
# Number of observations: 12 
# R-squared: 0.992
```

Answer (score -1):

The data shows an interaction. Try to fit a different model, logistic is not appropriate.

```
with(my_data, interaction.plot(A, B, Y, fixed = TRUE, col = 2:3, type = "l"))
```

[image]
An analysis of variance shows clear significance for all factors and interaction.

```
fit <- aov(Y~(A*B),data=my_data)
summary(fit)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
A            1 0.2002  0.2002   130.6 3.11e-06 ***
B            1 1.1224  1.1224   732.0 3.75e-09 ***
A:B          1 0.2494  0.2494   162.7 1.35e-06 ***
Residuals    8 0.0123  0.0015                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Is `Y` really continuous or a proportion bounded by 0 and 1? If the latter is the case, ANOVA is not applicable to this case.

Comment: Well, the information  in the Original is "Y continuous variable".

Comment: I know, but the data says otherwise. I was just wondering why OP would come up with the idea to use GLM in the first place.

Comment: ANOVA is applicable, it is just that the assumption of normally distributed homoscedastic errors could likely be violated here. Which is easily checked through plot(fit). Standard errors may thus be over- or underestimated, and the p-values under- or overestimated. But fitting a GLM (which also encompasses the LM) does not seem like a very bad choice here.